# Nested Fragment inside of Fragment Tabhost having problems getting context & inflater

Tags: android, android-fragments, nested, android-context, fragment-tab-host

I am using `actionbarsherlock` and a `tabhost` of fragments and in one of my tabs I display a fragment called `segmentedControlFrag` that includes 4 segmented control buttons(labeled "2hrs", "8hrs", "24hrs" and "1wk") and a frame that takes up the rest of the screen.

When one of the buttons from the `segmentedcontrol` group is selected a `async` request grabs some important info , the frame is replaced with a  new `(visualFragmentFrag)` fragment which includes the important info from the request in as a extra.

It works just fine, I can click each of the buttons from the segmented control group and they each load their own variation of `visualTrendsFrag` just fine. I can even select a completely different tab and return and it will load up on the segmented control I last selected just fine.

The problem only starts when I add this line of code inside `onCreateView` of the `segmentedControlFrag`:

```
segmentText.check(R.id.button_one);
```

The issues in the logcat when I add this line of code are null pointer errors all relating to context. While it does work if I leave out the line above I suspect the way I am managing fragments in `segmentedControlFrag` is wrong as well.

segmentedControlFrag:

```
public class TrendsSegmentedControlFrame extends SherlockFragment {

 private ImageButton update_btn;
 private View view;
 private LayoutInflater myInflater;
 private ViewGroup myContainer;
 SegmentedRadioGroup segmentText;
 SegmentedRadioGroup segmentImg;
 private String hoursVar="2";
 private static final int TWO_HRS = 1;
 private static final int EIGHT_HRS = 2;
 private static final int TWENTYFOUR_HRS = 3;
 private static final int ONE_WEEK = 4;

    private int mTabState=0;
 
 
 
 @Override
 public LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag", "getLayoutInflater");
  return super.getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState);
 
 }
 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag", "onActivityCreated");
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 }
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag", "onCreate");
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag", "onDestroy");
  super.onDestroy();
  
 }
 @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag", "onDestroyView");
  super.onDestroyView();
  
 }

 @Override
 public void onPause() {
  Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag", "onPause");
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPause();
 }
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
  Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag", "onResume");
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onResume();
 }
 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag", "onSaveInstanceState");
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 }
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag", "onStart");
  
  super.onStart();
 }
 @Override
 public void onStop() {
  Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag", "onStop");
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onStop();
 }
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_segmented_control_frame, container, false);

  segmentText = (SegmentedRadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.segment_text);
  RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
  
  
  segmentText.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag-onCheckChangedCalled","");

    
    LocationInfo locationInfo = new LocationInfo(getActivity());
    String latitude = Float.toString(locationInfo.lastLat);
    String longitude = Float.toString(locationInfo.lastLong);

    
    if (checkedId == R.id.button_one) {
     Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag-onCheckChanged","button_one | 2hrs");
     hoursVar="2";

     RequestParams params= new RequestParams();
     params.put("loggedin_uid", TabHostFragmentActivity.loggedin_uid);
     params.put("hours", hoursVar);
     params.put("long", longitude);
     params.put("lat", latitude);

     RestClient.post(TabHostFragmentActivity.token,TREND_COUNT_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, JSONObject arg1) {
       //NEED TO ADD CODE IN CASE OF FAIL

      }
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {

       String trend_count="0";
       int trend_count_int=0;
       try {
        trend_count=json.getString("trend_count");

       } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       trend_count_int=Integer.parseInt(trend_count);
       if(trend_count_int>0){
        Log.i("hoursVar:"+hoursVar+" | trend_count:"+trend_count, "TrendsSegmentedContrlolFrag");
        Fragment visualTrends = new VisualTrendsFrag();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("hoursVar", hoursVar);
        args.putString("trend_count", trend_count);
        visualTrends.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

        if (fm != null) {
         FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
         ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, visualTrends);
         ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

       }else{
        Log.i("trends_count was 0", "TrendsSegmentedContrlolFrag");
       }
      }
     }); 
     //mToast.setText("Displaying all users you've been near in the last 2 hours");


    } else if (checkedId == R.id.button_two) {
     hoursVar="8";
     Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag-onCheckChanged","button_two | 8hrs");
     

     RequestParams params= new RequestParams();
     params.put("loggedin_uid", TabHostFragmentActivity.loggedin_uid);
     params.put("hours", hoursVar);
     params.put("long", longitude);
     params.put("lat", latitude);

     RestClient.post(TabHostFragmentActivity.token,TREND_COUNT_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, JSONObject arg1) {
       //NEED TO ADD CODE IN CASE OF FAIL

      }
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {

       String trend_count="0";
       int trend_count_int=0;
       try {
        trend_count=json.getString("trend_count");

       } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       trend_count_int=Integer.parseInt(trend_count);
       if(trend_count_int>0){
        Log.i("hoursVar:"+hoursVar+" | trend_count:"+trend_count, "TrendsSegmentedContrlolFrag");
        Fragment visualTrends = new VisualTrendsFrag();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("hoursVar", hoursVar);
        args.putString("trend_count", trend_count);
        visualTrends.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

        if (fm != null) {
         FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
         ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, visualTrends);
         ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

       }else{
        Log.i("trends_count was 0", "TrendsSegmentedContrlolFrag");
       }
      }
     }); 
     //mToast.setText("Displaying all users you've been near in the last 2 hours");


    

    } else if (checkedId == R.id.button_three) {
     hoursVar="24";

     
     Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag-onCheckChanged","button_three | 24hrs");
     
     RequestParams params= new RequestParams();
     params.put("loggedin_uid", TabHostFragmentActivity.loggedin_uid);
     params.put("hours", hoursVar);
     params.put("long", longitude);
     params.put("lat", latitude);

     RestClient.post(TabHostFragmentActivity.token,TREND_COUNT_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, JSONObject arg1) {
       //NEED TO ADD CODE IN CASE OF FAIL

      }
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {

       String trend_count="0";
       int trend_count_int=0;
       try {
        trend_count=json.getString("trend_count");

       } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       trend_count_int=Integer.parseInt(trend_count);
       if(trend_count_int>0){
        Log.i("hoursVar:"+hoursVar+" | trend_count:"+trend_count, "TrendsSegmentedContrlolFrag");
        
        Fragment visualTrends = new VisualTrendsFrag();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("hoursVar", hoursVar);
        args.putString("trend_count", trend_count);
        visualTrends.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

        if (fm != null) {
         FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
         ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, visualTrends);
         ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

       }else{
        Log.i("trends_count was 0", "TrendsSegmentedContrlolFrag");
       }
      }
     }); 
     //mToast.setText("Displaying all users you've been near in the last 2 hours");


    

    }else if (checkedId == R.id.button_four) {
     hoursVar="168";


     
     Log.i("TrendsSegControlFrag-onCheckChanged","button_four | 168hrs");
     
     RequestParams params= new RequestParams();
     params.put("loggedin_uid", TabHostFragmentActivity.loggedin_uid);
     params.put("hours", hoursVar);
     params.put("long", longitude);
     params.put("lat", latitude);

     RestClient.post(TabHostFragmentActivity.token,TREND_COUNT_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, JSONObject arg1) {
       //NEED TO ADD CODE IN CASE OF FAIL

      }
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {

       String trend_count="0";
       int trend_count_int=0;
       try {
        trend_count=json.getString("trend_count");

       } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       trend_count_int=Integer.parseInt(trend_count);
       if(trend_count_int>0){
        Log.i("hoursVar:"+hoursVar+" | trend_count:"+trend_count, "TrendsSegmentedContrlolFrag");
        
        Fragment visualTrends = new VisualTrendsFrag();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("hoursVar", hoursVar);
        args.putString("trend_count", trend_count);
        visualTrends.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

        if (fm != null) {
         FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
         ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, visualTrends);
         ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

       }else{
        Log.i("trends_count was 0", "TrendsSegmentedContrlolFrag");
       }
      }
     }); 
     //mToast.setText("Displaying all users you've been near in the last 2 hours");


    

    }

   }
  });

  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   segmentText.check(R.id.button_one);

            
        }

  
  //code goes here
  return view;
 }

}
```

**VisualTrendsFrag(the frag being nested inside the frame of segmentedControlFrag:**

```
public class VisualTrendsFrag extends SherlockFragment {





 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (getArguments() != null) {
  
   hoursVar=getArguments().getString("hoursVar");
   trend_count=getArguments().getString("trend_count");
   trend_count_int=Integer.parseInt(trend_count);
   Log.i("hoursVar",hoursVar);
   Log.i("trend_count",trend_count);
  }
  

  
  
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
  if(randomInt==0){
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_ten_a, container, false);
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","ten_a");

  }else if(randomInt==1){
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_ten_b, container, false);
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","ten_b");

  }else if(randomInt==2){
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_ten_c, container, false);
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","ten_c");

  }else if(randomInt==3){
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_ten_d, container, false);
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","ten_d");

  }else if(randomInt==4){
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_ten_e, container, false);
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","ten_e");

  }else if(randomInt==5){
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_ten_f, container, false);
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","ten_f");

  }else if(randomInt==6){
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_ten_g, container, false);
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","ten_g");

  }
  
  if(trend_count_int==0){
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_empty, container, false);
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","trends_linear_layout_empty");   
  }else if(trend_count_int==1){   
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_one_view, container, false);
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","trends_linear_layout_one_view"); 
  }else if(trend_count_int==2){
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_two_views, container, false);
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","trends_linear_layout_two_views"); 
  }else if(trend_count_int==3){
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_three_views, container, false);
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","trends_linear_layout_three_views");
  }else if(trend_count_int==4){
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","trends_linear_layout_four_views");
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_four_views, container, false);
  }else if(trend_count_int==5){
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","trends_linear_layout_five_views");
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_five_views, container, false);
  }else if(trend_count_int==6){
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","trends_linear_layout_six_views");
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_six_views, container, false);
  }else if(trend_count_int==7){
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","trends_linear_layout_seven_views");
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_seven_views, container, false);
  }else if(trend_count_int==8){
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","trends_linear_layout_eight_views");
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_eight_views, container, false);
  }else if(trend_count_int==9){
   Log.i("VisualTrendsFrag | Selected Layout: ","trends_linear_layout_nine_views");
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_linear_layout_nine_views, container, false);
  }
  
  Log.i("trend_count_int:",String.valueOf(trend_count_int));
  if(trend_count_int>=1){
   TrendBtn1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
   TrendBtn1.setVisibility(TrendBtn1.GONE);
  }
  if(trend_count_int>=2){
   TrendBtn2 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Button02);
   TrendBtn2.setVisibility(TrendBtn2.GONE);
  }
  if(trend_count_int>=3){
   TrendBtn3 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Button03);
   TrendBtn3.setVisibility(TrendBtn3.GONE);
  }
  if(trend_count_int>=4){
   TrendBtn4 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Button04);
   TrendBtn4.setVisibility(TrendBtn4.GONE);
  }
  if(trend_count_int>=5){
   TrendBtn5 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Button05);
   TrendBtn5.setVisibility(TrendBtn5.GONE);
   
  }
  if(trend_count_int>=6){
   TrendBtn6 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Button06);
   TrendBtn6.setVisibility(TrendBtn6.GONE);
   
  }
  if(trend_count_int>=7){
   TrendBtn7 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Button07);
   TrendBtn7.setVisibility(TrendBtn7.GONE);
  }
  if(trend_count_int>=8){
   TrendBtn8 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Button08);
   TrendBtn8.setVisibility(TrendBtn8.GONE);
  }
  if(trend_count_int>=9){
   TrendBtn9 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Button09);
   TrendBtn9.setVisibility(TrendBtn9.GONE);
  }
  if(trend_count_int>=10){
   TrendBtn10 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Button10);
   TrendBtn10.setVisibility(TrendBtn10.GONE);
   
  }
  
  token = TabHostFragmentActivity.token;
  LocationInfo locationInfo = new LocationInfo(getActivity());
  String latitude = Float.toString(locationInfo.lastLat);
  String longitude = Float.toString(locationInfo.lastLong);
  Log.i("Lat", latitude);
  Log.i("long", longitude); 
  

  Log.i("VisualTrends is attempting to make a request",hoursVar);

  Log.i("HOURS VAR", hoursVar);
  try {
   new Requests().refreshTrends(hoursVar);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }





  //code goes here
  return view;
 }


 class Requests {
  
  
  
  

  public void refreshTrends(String hours) throws JSONException {




   LocationInfo locationInfo = new LocationInfo(getSherlockActivity());
   String latitude = Float.toString(locationInfo.lastLat);
   String longitude = Float.toString(locationInfo.lastLong);
   Log.i("Lat", latitude);
   Log.i("long", longitude); 
   pdialog = ProgressHUD.show(getSherlockActivity(),"Loading", false,false);



   // Creating JSON Parser instance
   RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

   params.put("loggedin_uid", TabHostFragmentActivity.loggedin_uid);
   params.put("lat", latitude);
   params.put("long", longitude);
   params.put("hours", hours);


   RestClient.post(token,TRENDS_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

    
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, JSONObject arg1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onFailure(arg0, arg1); 

    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {



     // Pull out the first event on the public timeline
     pdialog.dismiss();
     try {

      trends = json.getJSONArray("trends");
      //int num_of_trends = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("trends_count"));
      //int num_of_views=10;
      



     } catch (JSONException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     /*if(trends == null){
      final LinearLayout main_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_main_layout);
      main_layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
      noFriends_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noFriends_tv);
      noFriends_tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
      noFriends_tv.setText("No topics or hashtags trending nearby currently. Post a status using a hashtag to start a local trend!");
      noFriends_tv.setVisibility(noFriends_tv.VISIBLE);
     }*/

     if(trends != null){
      
      



      try{

       Log.i("friends response", trends.toString());
       // looping through All Contacts
       for(int i = 0; i < trends.length(); i++){


        JSONObject c = trends.getJSONObject(i);

        // Storing each json item in variable
        String hashtag = c.getString("hashtag");
        String count = c.getString("COUNT( * )");
        int trendObjectCount=i+1;


        if(trendObjectCount==1){



         TrendBtn1.setText(hashtag+"("+count+")");
         TrendBtn1.setVisibility(TrendBtn1.VISIBLE);
         TrendBtn1.setOnClickListener(new quickActionMenu(hashtag));

        }

        if(trendObjectCount==2){



         TrendBtn2.setText(hashtag+"("+count+")");
         TrendBtn2.setVisibility(TrendBtn2.VISIBLE);
         TrendBtn2.setOnClickListener(new quickActionMenu(hashtag));
         

        }

        if(trendObjectCount==3){


         TrendBtn3.setText(hashtag+"("+count+")");
         TrendBtn3.setVisibility(TrendBtn3.VISIBLE);
         TrendBtn3.setOnClickListener(new quickActionMenu(hashtag));

        }
        if(trendObjectCount==4){

         TrendBtn4.setText(hashtag+"("+count+")");
         TrendBtn4.setVisibility(TrendBtn4.VISIBLE);
         TrendBtn4.setOnClickListener(new quickActionMenu(hashtag));
        }
        if(trendObjectCount==5){


         TrendBtn5.setText(hashtag+"("+count+")");
         TrendBtn5.setVisibility(TrendBtn5.VISIBLE);
         TrendBtn5.setOnClickListener(new quickActionMenu(hashtag));

        }
        if(trendObjectCount==6){


         TrendBtn6.setText(hashtag+"("+count+")");
         TrendBtn6.setVisibility(TrendBtn6.VISIBLE);
         TrendBtn6.setOnClickListener(new quickActionMenu(hashtag));

        }
        if(trendObjectCount==7){


         TrendBtn7.setText(hashtag+"("+count+")");
         TrendBtn7.setVisibility(TrendBtn7.VISIBLE);
         TrendBtn7.setOnClickListener(new quickActionMenu(hashtag));

        }
        if(trendObjectCount==8){


         TrendBtn8.setText(hashtag+"("+count+")");
         TrendBtn8.setVisibility(TrendBtn8.VISIBLE);
         TrendBtn8.setOnClickListener(new quickActionMenu(hashtag));

        }

        if(trendObjectCount==9){


         TrendBtn9.setText(hashtag+"("+count+")");
         TrendBtn9.setVisibility(TrendBtn9.VISIBLE);
         TrendBtn9.setOnClickListener(new quickActionMenu(hashtag));

        }
        if(trendObjectCount==10){


         TrendBtn10.setText(hashtag+"("+count+")");
         TrendBtn10.setVisibility(TrendBtn10.VISIBLE);
         TrendBtn10.setOnClickListener(new quickActionMenu(hashtag));

        }

       }

      } catch (JSONException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }

     





    }
   });


  }
 }
 
 
 

 public class quickActionMenu implements OnClickListener{
     private int position;
  private String clicked_uid;
  QuickAction mQuickAction ;
  String selectedTopic;
  
  
  public quickActionMenu(String topic){
    mQuickAction  = new QuickAction(getActivity());
      selectedTopic=topic;
      ActionItem viewStatuses   = new ActionItem(ID_VIEW, "View Statuses", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add));
   ActionItem hashtagSubscribe  = new ActionItem(ID_SUBSCRIBE, "Subscribe", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_up));
        
        
 
   
    mQuickAction.addActionItem(viewStatuses);
    mQuickAction.addActionItem(hashtagSubscribe);
   
   //setup the action item click listener
    mQuickAction.setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
     private TrendsAdapter hashtagAdapter;

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(QuickAction quickAction, int pos, int actionId) {
      ActionItem actionItem = quickAction.getActionItem(pos);

      if (actionId == ID_VIEW) {

       

        FragmentManager fm = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        HashtagSearchFeedDialog hashDialog = new HashtagSearchFeedDialog().newInstance(selectedTopic);
        hashDialog.show(fm, "dialog");
      


      } else if(actionId == ID_SUBSCRIBE){



       pdialog = ProgressHUD.show(getSherlockActivity(),"Loading", false,false);
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        
        params.put("loggedin_uid", TabHostFragmentActivity.loggedin_uid);
        params.put("hashtag", selectedTopic);




        RestClient.post(token,SUBSCRIBE_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, JSONObject arg1) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);
          pdialog.dismiss();
          Log.i("Request Failed:", arg1.toString());
          Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), arg1.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

         @Override
         public void onSuccess(JSONObject requestResponse) {
          pdialog.dismiss();
          if(requestResponse!=null){

           Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), 
             selectedTopic+" has been added to your hashtag subscriptions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }


         }
        });
       







      }
     }
    });
   


      
     
     }
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
   mQuickAction.show(v);
   Log.i("Hashtag Selected:"+selectedTopic, "VisualTrendsFrag");
         
          
  }
     
    }
 
 
}
```

EDIT: Im begining to think its not so much a context issue as it is a LayoutInflator issue, here is the lib im using that is causing the "popupwindow errors in the logcat below" :
https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Android are you compiling against? As far as i know, nested fragments isn´t supported in versions before 4.2.